# Does anyone know this error ? KeyError: 18

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter

I'm working with`graphics.py`. Its a basic function based "easy" derivative of Tkinter

I'm working on a game and if I try the undraw() method, i get this error

**Code has been removed due to privacy issues**

Full Traceback:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1442, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)   File "C:\Users\Benny\Google Drive\PSAP\Assignments\Assignment_2_PSP\Assignment_2_Part2\Assign2_Part2.py",
line 38, in handleKeys
    play_game()   File "C:\Users\Benny\Google Drive\PSAP\Assignments\Assignment_2_PSP\Assignment_2_Part2\Assign2_Part2.py",
line 100, in play_game
    i.undraw()   File "C:\Users\Benny\Google Drive\PSAP\Assignments\Assignment_2_PSP\Assignment_2_Part2\game.py",
line 115, in undraw
    self.image.undraw()   File "C:\Users\Benny\Google Drive\PSAP\Assignments\Assignment_2_PSP\Assignment_2_Part2\graphics.py",
line 783, in undraw
    del self.imageCache[self.imageId]  # allow gc of tk photoimage KeyError: 6
```

Comment: Where's the source of `undraw()`?

Comment: Ok, sorry I will give you the full error if you like

Comment: In Version 4.2 5/26/2011 of the [`graphics.py`](http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics.py) file I found, there's a `try/except KeyError` around the `del self.imageCache[self.imageId]` statement, which would suppress the exception you're getting. Perhaps this is a newer version, and you should be using it instead.

Comment: lol, actually it was running graphics.py from the wrong location. well I didn't mean to I put graphics.py in the correct location but I had it in another location outside of python Lib that python check first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means your dictionary has no key `18`:

```
>>> d = {1:2, 3:4}
>>> d[18]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 18
```

You can catch the exception and ignore it, like this:

```
try:
    del self.imageCache[self.imageId]
except KeyError:
    pass
```

Comment: FWIW I think it's missing key `6`.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the actual key is since the same exception will be raised.